# Python error conexión: MySQL Version '3.23.54-nt-log' is not supported

Tags: mysql, python

necesito conectarme mediante python a una base de datos MYSQL pero que desde el script que lanzo me devuelve:  MySQL Version '3.23.54-nt-log' is not supported.

He creado métodos con mysql.connector y pymysql, que funcionan ambos en MYSQL 8.0.12 y un MYSQL versión instalada en ubuntu 5.5.20, pero en esta versión 3.23.54 no lo permiten.

¿Qué driver de conexión necesito para conectarme a esta versión tan antigua?

Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este conector https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/, tienes un ejemplo en esa web.

Comment: Muchas gracias, antes de leer tu respuesta encontré -tras larga búsqueda- el conector que citas y me ha ido perfecto.  La instalación la realicé en python 2.7 con pip install .gz del fichero .gz descargable del enlace.  Una vez instalado y con pandas migré una base de datos entera de un servidor a otro con una versión actual de MySQL en 3 minutos.